# "Гори оно синим пламенем!"

Tags: фразеология

"Пропади оно пропадом", "гори оно синим пламенем" - так говорят, ставя крест на чем-либо. Но вот интересно, откуда пошло выражение про "синие пламя"? Почему оно именно синее?
Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Гореть синим пламенем

Синий газовый огонь, горящий ныне чуть не во всякой кухне, нашим предкам был знаком лишь в самых критических ситуациях: если глухой ночью заявиться на кладбище или влезть в топкое болото. Метан в природе образуется при гниении органических остатков без доступа кислорода. Обычно это явление наблюдается именно в болоте или рядом со свежими могилами, недаром тривиальное название метана - болотный газ. При этом в качестве примеси могут образовываться следовые количества пентагидрида фосфора; это вещество немедленно вспыхивает на воздухе и поджигает остальной газ. Днём разглядеть горящий метан практически невозможно, а вот ночью болотные и могильные огоньки хорошо заметны. Поверье связывает появление синих огоньков с мытарствами неприкаянных душ: грешников, умерших без покаяния, самоубийц и просто людей, утонувших в болоте.

Считается, что это горят их души, мучения которых начались ещё прежде страшного суда. Так что нетрудно представить, какой мрачный смысл вкладывали наши предки в выражение "гореть синим пламенем". И сейчас, когда человек утверждает, что он горит синим пламенем, это значит, что он попал в чрезвычайно затруднительное положение, из которого не может выбраться самостоятельно. Порой случается услышать, как кто-то, восклицает: "Да гори оно всё синим пламенем!" Это значит, что человек потерял последнюю надежду устроить какое-то дело как следует, и полностью махнул на него рукой.
Источник:http://www.otrezal.ru/catch-words/541.html